# ¿Como puedo crear commits con mensajes automáticos?

Tags: linux, git, bash

Estoy intentando crear una función en bash script para automatizar los mensajes al hacer `git commit -S -am 'Message'`, dependiendo del archivo creado, eliminado o modificado.

Pero no se como hacerlo y recién cree un función, donde me ahorra un poco de trabajo pero aun tengo añadir manualmente los mensajes de cada commit.

Este es mi código:

```sh
function gitpush () {
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    git add .
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
      echo "No commit message"
    else
      git commit -S -am "$2"
    fi
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      echo "No repository selected"
    else
      git push $1 master
    fi
  else
    echo false
  fi
}
gitpush origin "Message"
```

Se, que con el comando `git status --porcelain` se pueden obtener la lista de los archivos afectados. E investigando un poco cree este pequeño comando.

```sh
git status --porcelain | \
  sed -e 's/\sD/Remove/g;s/\sM/Update/g;s/\s??/Create/g' | \
  awk -F: '{
    print "git commit -S -am " $1 $2
  }'
```

Pero no me funcionó :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente te habías confudido: `\s` se utiliza para representar espacios en blanco, mientras `$` se usa para representar el comienzo de una nueva línea (al menos en expresiones regulares POSIX, que son las que `sed` usa). Corrigiendo eso tu código quedaría así:

```sh
git status --porcelain | \
    sed -e "s/^\s*D/Remove/g;s/^\s*M/Update/g;s/^\s*A/Create/g;s/\s\s/ /g;s/\n//" | \
    awk -F: '{print "git commit -S -am  \"$1 $2\""}'
```

Lo que hice fue reemplazar `\s` en tu código por `$\s*`, que significa "Comienzo de línea y cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco".

Y, por ejemplo, al actualizar el archivo `README.txt`, crear el archivo `LICENSE` y borrar el archivo `.log.bak`, la salida sería la siguiente:

```sh
git commit -S -am "Update README.md"
git commit -S -am "Create LICENSE"
git commit -S -am "Remove .log.bak"
```

Comment: Interesante, pero a mi me aparece `??` en lugar de `A` para nuevos archivos añadidos al repositorio

Comment: Aunque no se, si es buena idea hacer el `git commit` antes del `git add`

Comment: En mi experiencia (y pruebas) las adiciones de archivos se marcan con `A`. Y respecto a lo de hacer `git commit` antes de `git add`, es prácticamente imposible. Quiero decir, el flujo de trabajo es `git add`, `git commit`. Además, `git status` solamente muestra los cambios añadidos con `git add`, pero que no tienen un commit correspondiente.

Comment: Entiendo, lo raro es que a mi `git status` me muestra los cambios antes de hacer `git add .` y después de hacer `git add .` ya no me muestra nada. Además de que las adiciones me las muestra con `??`

Comment: Hmm... realmente extraño. ¿Estás trabajando con un servidor local?

Comment: desde un terminal aislado con un terminal para android llamado Termux, pero retiro lo dicho si me muestra los cambios después de hacer `git add .`. Creo que por que ya había echo `git commit` por eso ya no me muestra los cambios

Comment: Ah, ok. Cualquier cosa decime.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108470/discussion-between-rimuru-tempest-and-alvarito050506).